# React hooks: Issue with React.memo and useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I played around with react hooks, and I came across an issue that I do not understand.

The code is here https://codesandbox.io/embed/hnrch-hooks-issue-dfk0t
The example has 2 simple components:

**App Component**

```
const App = () => {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
  const [str, setStr] = useState();

  const inc = () => {
    setNum(num + 1);
    setStr(num >= 5 ? ">= 5" : "< 5");
    console.log(num);
  };

  const button = <button onClick={inc}>++</button>;

  console.log("parent rerender", num);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>App</h1>
      <Child str={str}>{button}</Child>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Child Component**

```
const Child = React.memo(
  ({ str, children }) => {
    console.log("child rerender");
    return (
      <div>
        <>
          <h2>Functional Child</h2>
          <p>{str}</p>
          {children}
        </>
      </div>
    );
  }
  (prev, props) => {
    return prev.str === props.str;
  }
);
```

So I have the child wrapped in a `React.memo`, and it should only rerender if `str` is different. But is also has children, and it get's passed a button which is incrementing a counter inside the parent (App).

The issue is: The counter will stop incrementing after it is set to 1. Can someone explain this issue to me and what I need to understand  to avoid those bugs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a "closure issue".

This is the first render time for `App`, the `inc` function has been created the first time: (let's call it `inc#1`)

```
const inc = () => {
  setNum(num + 1);
  setStr(num >= 5 ? ">= 5" : "< 5");
  console.log(num);
};
```

In the `inc#1` scope, `num` is currently `0`. The function is then passed to `button` which is then passed to `Child`.

All good so far. Now you press the button, `inc#1` is invoked, which mean that

```
setNum(num + 1);
```

where `num === 0` happen. `App` is re-rendered, *but* `Child` is not. The condition is if `prev.str === props.str` then we don't render again Child.

We are in the second render of `App` now, but `Child` still own the `inc#1` instance, where `num` is `0`.

You see where the problem is now? You will still invoke that function, but `inc` is now stale.

You have multiple ways to solve the issue. You could make sure that `Child` has always the updated props.

Or you could pass a callback to `setState` to fetch the current value ( instead of the stale one that live in the scope of the closure ). This is also an option:

```
const inc = () => {
  setNum((currentNum) => currentNum + 1);
};

React.useEffect(() => {
  setStr(num >= 5 ? ">= 5" : "< 5");
}, [num])
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things here.

1. If you are modifying a state and its new value depends on the previous value of the state, use `setState`'s functional form:

```
 setNum(num => num + 1);
```

2. `setState` is async, so when you try to `setStr`, the num value is not updated yet. Even more, in your particular case `inc` is closing over (i.e. creates a closure) `num` value from the state, so inside that function it'll always have its initial value - `0`.
   To fix this you need to use the Effect hook to update the string when `num` changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setStr(num >= 5 ? ">= 5" : "< 5");
  }, [num]) // Track the 'num' var here
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix the bug was changing `inc` function to this:

```
const inc = () => {
  setNum(n => {
    const newNum = n + 1;
    setStr(newNum >= 5 ? ">= 5" : "< 5");
    return newNum;
  });
};
```

Note that setState is now passed a callback function, which receives the old value and returns the new one. That way, the "closure" issue was resolved.