# React.memo issue with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, react-memo

I have two components.

```
function Parent(props){

  const handleClick = () => {
   console.log(props.stateA);
  };

  return <div><Child text={stateB} handleClick={handleClick} /></div>
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    stateA: state.stateA // stateA will be changed somewhere else
    stateB: state.stateB
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Parent);
```

```
function Child(props) {
   return <div onClick={props.handleClick}>{props.text}</div>
}

export default React.memo(Child,(prev, next) => {
   return prev.text === next.text
});
```

My problem is when stateA is changed somewhere, clicking on `Child` will log the previous stateA. I can't access the latest stateA.

You can see, I don't want to `Child` re-render when stateA changes,it should re-render only when stateB changed. But I want to access the latest stateA in `Parent` when clicking on `Child`.

Is there any method to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the `Parent` component is a **functional component** then you can use like this

```
 const [valueA, setValueA] = useState('')
 useEffect(() => {
      setValueA(props.stateA)
 },[props.stateA])

 console.log(valueA) // latest Value of stateA
 return <div><Child text={stateB} handleClick={handleClick} /></div>
```

I hope it'll work for you.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. Your method is like this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57543996/react-hooks-issue-with-react-memo-and-usestate

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access `props.stateA` no problem

```
const handleClick = () => {
   console.log(props.stateA);
};
```

because you accessing parent's props in `handleClick`. So if `props.stateA` is stale then the logical conclusion is the parent doesn't receive the latest props. Can we see how you update props/state?

Comment: The Parent received stateA indeed. I have tried {props.stateA} to show it in dom

Comment: So props.stateA is not stale? try to test this `const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
   console.log(props.stateA);
},[props.stateA]);`

Comment: It still get the same result. I know it's just like this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57543996/react-hooks-issue-with-react-memo-and-usestate
But I don't know how to solve it in my situation.

Comment: I see. There is no easy solution in that case because Child will always have a stale version of `handleClick` with your `memo` condition. I would suggest to drop memo from parent and only use it on a Child that actually needs it. I think I've learned something new myself

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a `ref` to `stateA` so it is what is logged when you call `handleClick`. `useRef` ensures that the last value is used.

```
function Parent(props){
  const stateARef = useRef(props.stateA);

  useEffect(() => {
    stateARef.current = props.stateA;
  }, [props.stateA])

  const handleClick = () => {
   console.log(stateARef.current);
  };

  return <div><Child text={stateB} handleClick={handleClick} /></div>
}
```

Comment: "Ensures that the last value is used is imprecise." Referring to the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref), "the returned object [ref] will persist for the full lifetime of the component."

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing has nothing to do with Redux.

The Parent component passes 2 props to the child: the text which is changed when needed and `handleClick` which is changed **each** render of the Parent component - a new function is created each time.

But the React.memo is checking only the text prop, so the child receives a stale `handleClick` quite often.

The correct solution is to wrap the `handleClick` with [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) and check all props in `React.memo` ([react does this](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) by default).

```
function Parent(props){

  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
   console.log(props.stateA);
  }, []);

  return <div><Child text={stateB} handleClick={handleClick} /></div>
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    stateA: state.stateA // stateA will be changed somewhere else
    stateB: state.stateB
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Parent);

function Child(props) {
   return <div onClick={props.handleClick}>{props.text}</div>
}

export default React.memo(Child);
```